# How to make the transition from Haskell type variables to C# generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, haskell

Currently I'm in migration from [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29) to [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29). There are so many new features in C#. How can I declare C# functions with type variables similar to Haskell?

```
map :: [a] -> (a -> b) -> [b]
```

I read about generics, but I can't put this information together properly.
Maybe something similar to:

```
delegate B MyFun<A,B>(A a);
List<B> Map<A, B>(List<A> list, MyFun<A,B> fun) ...
```

Comment: You got it. The code you posted is correct. Any problems with it?

Comment: I dont know, i have no Visual Studio installed yet.

Comment: When going from Haskell to c#, I translate code into C# instead of trying to program in C# as if it were Haskell. The native C# way to say `map` is the Select extender, which is already defined by the LINQ libraries. It's IEnumerable<TItem>.Select(Func<TItem, TResult>). In C#, this same name will usually be used for `fmap` on anything that's would have been a `Functor` in Haskell.

Answer (score 3):

First, naming standards in C# are a little more comfortable, so try giving "real" names instead of A or B (TKey/TValue) for example.
Second, we have Action and Func that are generic delegates for procedures and functions. You can use those too.
As was suggested in comments, you should use the most general types you can to make the code less susceptible to change so...

```
IEnumerable<TResult> Map<TItem, TResult>(
    IEnumerable<TItem> items, 
    Func<TItem, TResult> mappingFunction)
```

Comment: Also to add to this, included with .NET are many extensions on the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, which is the most generic interface for a sequence of values. These extensions include many common operators including `Map` (although it goes by the name of `Select`).

Comment: IEnumerable is pretty much haskell's list monad.